# Is there a way to check if Google Drive is scanning folders other than the ones I have synced?

Tags: google, google-apps, synchronization

I have a piece of software that monitors C:\Folder1. It keeps it in sync with C:\Folder2. It encrypts everything in C:\Folder2.

I want to sync Folder2 to my Google Drive. But this additional encryption step is silly if they could scan my entire file system now that they're downloaded to my machine.

Is there a way to check what files a program accesses?

Is it already common knowledge that Google does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process Monitor.  This was developed by Mark Russinovich and was then bought out by Microsoft who gave Russinovich a job.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity

It can be a chatty old application to monitor though, so you might want to turn off AV and anything else that is running in the background.